# Translate windows serial port code to Macos

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, serial-port

I have been struggling to translate this specific code, so it works on my Xcode program without the windows.h file. Does anybody have some ideas about how I can make it work?

Thank you in advance

This is the following code:

```
COMPort::COMPort ( const char * const portName )
  : theDCB (NULL)
{

thePortHandle = (unsigned ) CreateFile ( portName
                                       , GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE
                                       , 0
                                       , NULL
                                       , OPEN_EXISTING
                                       , FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING
                                       , NULL
                                       );
if (thePortHandle == HFILE_ERROR)
{
   throw runtime_error ("COMPort: failed to open.");
} 

theDCB = new char [sizeof(DCB)];
getState();
setBlockingMode();
setHandshaking();

} 


COMPort::~COMPort()
{

delete [] theDCB;


if (CloseHandle ((HANDLE)thePortHandle) == FALSE )
{
   throw runtime_error ("COMPort: failed to close.");
} 
}
```

Comment: Windows and macOS are two *very* different systems. Code tailored for one system will not work on the other. However, macOS is a POSIX system (like Linux) so there are plenty of books, tutorials and examples available that can be used for either Linux or macOS (the main difference being the names of the device files).

Comment: On another note, why `theDCB = new char [sizeof(DCB)];` instead of just `theDCB = new DCB;`? Or better yet don't use pointers and dynamic allocation at all.

Comment: You're probably better off using an existing cross platform serial port library, e.g. [boost asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port.html) or many others

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are rewriting Windows code for serial communication. Windows and macOS are very different in this respect.

You will find many examples of how to do this, e.g.: https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J73/15.5

- `CreateFile` translates to `open`
- `CloseHandle` translates to `close`
- The `DCB` struct translates to `termios` and is probably only needed temporarily for setting baud rate.

Most likely, your code also uses `GetComm` and `SetComm`. Those would translate to `tcgetattr`, `tcsetattr` and possibly `cfsetispeed` and `cfsetospeed`.

When it comes to concurrently writing to and reading from a serial port, macOS is much simpler than Windows where it is mutually exclusive unless non-blocking I/O is used. On macOS, reading and writing are independent.

If you also translate your code to Linux as well, you will find that macOS and Linux are almost the same.